# Elastic Search truncating hits.total via score

Tags: elasticsearch, filtering

Is it possible to execute a `query` and filter it so that only elements with `score` > 1.0 are considered in the `hits.total` response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can use `min_score` to achieve this (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/min-score/). The ES docs example:

```
{
    "min_score": 0.5,
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```

As the docs also say, this isn't usually practical because scoring is a relative calculation.  If you're heavily influencing the results however, it might be what you need.

Comment: Thanks! Somehow I was missing the "search" documentation :|